# SQL Server 2008 : IF statement not working as expected

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a procedure which maps values from a table to a comma-joined string for a report.

Unfortunately, due to an user-interface bug, some of the values are `'none'` as opposed to `null`.  I'm pretty sure the `'none'` value is just a string, so my procedure tries to handle it as such.

The procedure should return nothing if it encounters `'none'`, but this isn't the case. For example, if I pass `'none'` to `@DrugUse` below, it should return nothing, right? It still returns `'d'`, though.  So what am I doing wrong?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MapConsumerAdvice] 
(
    @AdultThemes as VarChar,
    @DrugUse as VarChar
)
RETURNS VarChar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result as VarChar(999)

    SET @Result = ''

    IF (@AdultThemes > 0) 
       SET @Result = ',' + 'a'

    IF (@DrugUse IS NOT NULL) AND (@DrugUse != 'none') 
        SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'd'

    RETURN SUBSTRING(@Result, 2, LEN(@Result))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a length on the `varchar` for the parameters:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[MapConsumerAdvice_version2] 
(
    @AdultThemes as VarChar(10),
    @DrugUse as VarChar(10)
)
```

If you do not put a length, then the value will have a length of one which does not equal `none` so it will return `d`. See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d8ca/4) of two different versions of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Books Online:

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ]
>
> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
> statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
> the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

Try:

```
-- Remark 1:
declare @a varchar = 'abcd'
select @a, len(@a)


-- Remark 2:
select cast(1.2345678901234567890123456789 as varchar)
```